# Android Two Tabs with same activity

Tags: android, android-layout

This should be really simple but it aint working.  What I want is two different tabs that use the same activity class. I don't care if they are sharing the same activity or if they each have their own instance.  In this code I set the second tab with the same activity as the first, but only the first will load in the app. If I click the second tab I get a black screen:

```
//Create tabs
    Resources res = getResources();
    TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();
    TabHost.TabSpec spec;
    Intent intent;
    String tabTitle = getString(R.string.livevideo);

    // Initialize intent
    // Initialize tabspec for each tab and add it to host
    intent = new Intent().setClass(this, CameraListView.class);
    spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("live").setIndicator(tabTitle,res.getDrawable(R.drawable.livebtn)).setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);

    tabTitle = getString(R.string.videoplayback);
    intent = new Intent().setClass(this, CameraListView.class);
    spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("playback").setIndicator(tabTitle,res.getDrawable(R.drawable.playbackbtn)).setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);
```

Can't this just be a simple thing? I would think that making a new intent with the same activity would instantiate a second copy of the activity, but perhaps that isn't how Android works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();
TabSpec spec = null;

tabSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec("tabSpec");
tabSpec.setIndicator(someString, someDrawable);
tabSpec.setContent(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), CameraListView.class));
tabHost.addTab(tabSpec);

tabSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec("tabSpec");
tabSpec.setIndicator(someString, someDrawable);
tabSpec.setContent(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), CameraListView.class));
tabHost.addTab(tabSpec);
```

**//EDIT**
In response to your question in comment. I don't know anything about any way to do what you're want to do. I had exactly the same problem. Finally I solved it by creating new Activity which  inherited from `firstTabActivity` and I put it in second tab. In your case I think it'll be quite simple - `SecondTabActivity` extends `FirstTabActivity` and overrides method `onListItemClick()`.

Comment: So they key here is to use the same tabspec name for both tabs.  This does get the same activity on both tabs, but I DO need each tab to have a distinct id. So these two tabs share a listview, but depending on the tab type will determine what activity is displayed when you select an item.  Any thoughts on how to reference the tabs as different while having the same activity?

Comment: Hello again :) No, tabSpec doesn't have to have same name for both tabs - as you can see in my code, I call twice tabSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec("tabSpec"); which means that tabSpec after second initialization is completely new instance, also parameter for method newTabSpec(String tag) doesn't have to be the same. To be honest I don't know where is difference between your and mine code :) Check my edited answer about the second part of your comment.

Answer (score 0):

Use different tags for every **tabspec** like this;

```
tabSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec("tabSpec");
tabSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec("tabSpec2");
```

Hope this helps.